# Is there a way to 'drive' lamps, similar to how you can 'drive' and control a camera in first person?

Tags: camera, light

In particular, I find the first person perspective and use of WASD very intuitive for when I'm positioning my camera in the scene.

I would like to know if there's a way to control lamps that same way in Blender?

I've used other software where you're able to control a light in the exact same way as you can the camera in blender and find it far easier and more intuitive to use then trying to move a light around in my scene by hand using the manipulators and rotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quirk of Blender is that you can actually set *any* object to be the 'camera' and use the <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> movement controls while in *Fly* mode.

1. Select the object (e.g. a lamp) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> to set it to be the camera. You will now be looking through the object like you would a camera object.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to enter *Fly* mode and navigate freely.

The downside of this is that you will then have to reassign the *actual* camera as the scene's active camera afterwards (if you intend to render anything) either by selecting it and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> or by selecting it in the *Scene* panel in the *Scene* tab of the *Properties* Editor:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When I look for the Point light in the Scene panel in the drop down for the Camera, the only option is the camera however. And when I Ctrl + 0 the Point light itself blender gives me an "Modifiers cannot be added to object: Point" error.

Comment: The zero has to be the zero on the numpad, otherwise blender will try to add a subsurf modifier to the light. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: That did it. Working like a charm!